# Stop parent component ripple being triggered from child component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

Let's say I have a simple code like:

```
<ListItem
  button={true}
>
  <Typography variant='caption' color='primary'>
            {value}
  </Typography>
  <Button
    onClick={foo}
  >
    Button
  </Button>
</ListItem>
```

When I click anything inside the ListItem the ripple effect is trigger, which is ok, but when I click the button I don't want the ripple effect of the parent component to be triggered. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `disableRipple` property of `ListItem`. Set it to `true` when clicking on button and set it to `false` when clicking on list item, something like:

```
const foo = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  parentDisableRipple: true
}));
const enableRipple = () => this.state.parentDisableRipple && this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  parentDisableRipple: false
}));

return (
  <div>
    <Hello name={this.state.name} />
    <p>
      Start editing to see some magic happen :)
    </p>

    <ListItem button={true} 
              disableRipple={this.state.parentDisableRipple}
              onClick={enableRipple()}>
      <Typography variant='caption' color='primary'>
        {value}
      </Typography>
      <Button onClick={foo} >Button</Button>
    </ListItem>
  </div>
);
```

I created a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fx2r1s) to play with

**UPDATE**

There is a [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374263/nesting-buttons-in-material-ui-how-to-disable-ripple-effect-of-container-button/57378155#answer-57378155) by @Domino987 using `onMouseDown` and `event.stopPropagation()` (already mentioned here by @vasanthcullen) and `<ListItemSecondaryAction>` wrapper.

I updated my STACKBLITZ with both these solutions

Comment: lolol. Cute and nice. Didn't expect it to work like that. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for  me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use event.stopPropagation() inside the click handler of the button. In your case, inside the foo() function

Comment: This is the solution I eventually found, but not really like that. I had to use OnMouseDown property and stop the propagation.

Comment: @CatalinLeca you are the boss, exactly it

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListItem button={true} matRipple #parent>
 <Typography variant='caption' color='primary' matRipple [matRippleTrigger]="parent"
   [matRippleDisabled]="true">
    {value}
 </Typography>
 <Button onClick={foo}>
    Button
 </Button>
</ListItem>
```

You need something like this:
Add Template variable that element which should be animated.
And trigger parent ripple by children with [matRippleTrigger] option.