# Nesting buttons in Material UI: how to disable ripple effect of container button while clicking on a child button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to nest one button into another (`IconButton` inside `ListItem` with `button` prop). The problem is that the `ListItem` ripple animation gets triggered even if I click on the `IconButton`. I want it to trigger only if I click directly on `ListItem` element

I've tried absolute positioning of `IconButton`, which didn't help

See the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-shape-fu6vo)

Comment: See my answer and STACKBLITZ example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447828/stop-parent-component-ripple-being-triggered-from-child-component/56457415#56457415

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either do it like this:

```
function App() {
  const mouseDown = e => {
    e.stopPropagation ();
  }
  return (
    <ListItem button>
      Some text
      <IconButton onMouseDown={mouseDown}>
        <Favorite />
      </IconButton>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

or by wrapping the Button in `<ListItemSecondaryAction>`which will also disable the ripple effect, but will move the icon to the end item, which can be fixed with some css.

Hope this helps. Happy coding

Comment: It is possible - please see my answer and STACKBLITZ example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447828/stop-parent-component-ripple-being-triggered-from-child-component/56457415#56457415

Comment: I added an easier solution with onMouseDown as well.

Comment: @Andriy, your STACKBLITZ  does not work for me unfortunately. But the onMouseDown solution I added works.

Comment: I agree, your solution is better @Domino987, I updated my original answer pointing to your solution. Thanks for sharing!